# data not committed in access using c#

Tags: c#

```
try {
    if (connection.con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) connection.con.Open();
    com = new OleDbCommand("insert into dealer values(@id,@a1,@a2,@a3,@a4,@a5,@a6)", connection.con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a1", int.Parse(t1.Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a2", t2.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a3", t3.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a4", t4.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a5", t5.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a6", t6.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a7", c1.Text);
    int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (i > 0) {
        MessageBox.Show("dealer Registration Seccessfully !!");
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
} finally {
    connection.con.Close();
}
```

data inserting into database show into database but after some it will delete automatically

Comment: com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a7", c1.Text);  where is '@a7' defined ? you also didn't use '@id'

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have a typo in your code, if the Id of table is not auto-increment just correct the arguments name:

```
try {
    if (connection.con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) connection.con.Open();
    com = new OleDbCommand("insert into dealer values(@id,@a1,@a2,@a3,@a4,@a5,@a6)", connection.con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(t1.Text)); // Change argument name to @id
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a1", t2.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a2", t3.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a3", t4.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a4", t5.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a5", t6.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a6", c1.Text);
    ...
```

And if the Id of table is auto-increment don't set its value in INSERT command.

Comment: Is parsing needed in AddWithValue ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi: I'm not sure, but I don't think so. He didn't specify the arguments type.

Comment: Logically says whatever i send, it passes as string later it go through conversion phase according to column data type.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi: Yes, to prevent run-time errors he should do that (I don't know the types), but there no compiler error for this code.